# Connecting to external database from Backand

Tags: ionic-framework, amazon-redshift, backand

I am currently working with a feature in our Ionic/Backand app that needs to access data from an external database (RedShift Cluster). I am thinking of the best way possible to accomplish this, and since we are using Backand as our backend, I thought if it was possible to make an action that could access RedShift Cluster and make SQL queries to it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option is

1. adding a generic [lambda function to access AWS redshift](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-redshift-loader),
2. Use AWS [API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) to expose this lambda to Back &, (it is as secure as you want it to be, utilizing API key and AWS secret and access tokens of the IAM user)
3. Then calling this API in Back& server-side JS action by using $http object is a breeze